# Changing bullet styles using DocX

Tags: novacode-docx

Does anybody know how to change bullet style using DocX ? I can add bullet lists, but can't figure out how to change the style to square bullets. I searched both the documentation and the source code on Github, to no avails.

Thanks in advance